# я сталкивался на проблему и не могу понять почему не работает isfocusable = true не работает

Tags: android, kotlin

После того как user заполнить свои данные я должен отключить нажатья на текствю

```
 val email = emailTxt.text.toString()
    val password = passwordTxt.text.toString()
    emailTxt.isFocusable = false
    passwordTxt.isFocusable = false
    loginBtn.isClickable = false
```

В этом случае текствю больше не откроет клавиатуру. А если user ввел неправилную данные больше клавиатура не откроеться хотя я сделаю

```
    emailTxt.isFocusable = true
passwordTxt.isFocusable = true
    loginBtn.isClickable = true
```

В респонсе и он фейлор в чем ошыбка нужно помощь я пиши на котлине.